# Is >= equal to > || === or > || == in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is the below if statement

```
if (a >= b)
```

Equal to this?

```
if (a > b || a === b)
```

Or is it equal to this?

```
if (a > b || a == b)
```

Comment: The === is also compare the value and type, otherwise the == compare the value. For me is equal if(a > b || a == b)

Comment: @Andrew `0`, `false`. That's why `==` and `===` exist separately in the first place.

Comment: @AndrewMorton `a = 0` and `b = '0'`

Comment: @Andrew The result is different depending on whether `==` or `===` is used. I fail to see the point you're trying to make.

Comment: The JavaScript equality table may help to understand the difference https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was comparing (3 >= "3") and was wondering if the `=` was standing for `==` or `===`. I couldn't really found an awnser. But the duplicate fully awnsers my question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is equivalent to `if(a > b || a == b)`

```js
var a = "2";
var b = 2;

console.log(a >= b); // true
console.log(a > b || a == b); // true (== compares value)
console.log(a > b || a === b); // false (=== compares value and type)
```

Comment: This isn't true when comparing objects, please consider the following example: `let obj1 = {a: 1}; let obj2 = {a: 1};` `obj1 >= obj2` would return true, but `obj1 > obj2 || obj1 == obj2` would return false !  (same thing when comparing `0` and `null`)

Comment: And if a and b are the same type, it is also equivalent to the === version. Hence it is not equivalent to one or another exclusively. Hence it depends.

Comment: @Jorge.V - In case of same type `==` is also true, hence, it becomes super set of same and different types

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal that is correct. And it doesn't change the fact that it depends, because it is also equivalent to === in some cases. By ignoring this I think you are missleading.

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza - Normally, we use relational operators for primitives and dates. Hence, the example seems to be breaking but it should not be used at first place

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first one

```
if(a >= b)
```

is similiar to

```
if(a > b || a == b)
```

but not equals to

```
if(a > b || a === b)
```

because in this last one you are even comparing the type of both the operands.

Example:
x = "5"

```
console.log(x==parseInt(x)) will return true
console.log(x===parseInt(x)) will return false
```

So, == does not consider the types of operands.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it in the console:

```
var a = 0;
var b = '0';

a == b; // true
a === b; // false
a >= b; // true
```

Ergo, `>=` is equivalent to `> || ==`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual result depend on the use case if the `typeof` both `a` & `b` is same then `(a >= b)` is same as `(a > b || a === b)`. This  is because `==` is equality with type coercion

```js
var a = "2";
var b = "2";

console.log(a >= b); // true
console.log(a > b || a == b); // true
console.log(a > b || a === b); // true


var a = "4";
var b = 4;

console.log(a >= b); // true
console.log(a > b || a == b); // true
console.log(a > b || a === b); // false
```

Answer (score -3):

It depends. If before the statement you had defined a or b with a different type,

```
if(a > b || a === b)
```

will return false if the first clause is not true. However if you didn't define a or b before both will have the same type and both expressions are equivalent.

You can understand "===" as

```
(a == b && sameType(a,b))
```

Comment: No, it does *not* depend on anything whether `>=` acts as `==` or `===`.

Comment: He isn't asking whether >= acts as == or ===, but if it is equivalent to one expression or the other. And it depends on what I said.